# Don't work bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy after upgrade Magento to 2.3.2

Tags: magento2, error, frontend, static-content-deploy

**Hello!**

When i run command **bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy** i give errors:

And my error:
useful.css):

> failed to open stream: No such file or directory

How to fix it? Thanks)

Comment: try to do with this command - sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: Please try this:  bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

Comment: All this does not work

Comment: Have you checked the version compatibility with your PHP and other modules?

Comment: Yes, and also I updated all the modules that needed this

Answer (score 0):

You need to change permissions or ownership of the project directory

To see who is currently logged user, run Linux command:

$whoami

To change the owner use the chown command:

```
$sudo chown -R username:username /magento-project-root
```

now run command for permission

```
$sudo chmod -R 755  /magento-project-root

cd magento-project-root

sudo chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated/

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

if still not working then check error at var/log directory

Comment: I did it and it didn’t help

Comment: What is error on var/log ?

Comment: run command  ls -l at root directory and check what is permissions for 'var, pub and generated' directory ?

Comment: I checked that I have the correct permissions for these directories: 777

Answer (score 0):

**Try below steps:-**

```
sudo rm -rf var/*
sudo rm -rf pub/static/frontend/*
sudo rm -rf generated/*

sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/(project name)/
sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade
sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
sudo php bin/magento ca:cl
sudo php bin/magento ca:fl
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/(project name)/
```

Hope it's works for you

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the folder ~ "var/www/project/design/frontend/Alias/mytheme/web/css/source", and run the command `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`
If everything goes well the problem is in the styles